# Create an hash using multi-index values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Let's suppose we have the following dataframe:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame(
columns = ['Film', 'Rating', 'Name'],
 data=[['Alien', 9, 'Jane'], ['Alien', 7, 'Mark'],
 ['LOTR', 8, 'Jack'], ['LOTR', 6, 'John']])

>> df.set_index(['Film', 'Rating'])
              Name
Film  Rating      
Alien 9       Jane
      7       Mark
LOTR  8       Jack
      6       John
```

I want to create an hash column using multi-index values, something like this:

```
              Name     hash
Film  Rating               
Alien 9       Jane  Alien/9
      7       Mark  Alien/7
LOTR  8       Jack   LOTR/8
      6       John   LOTR/6
```

Tried this:

```
df['hash'] = df.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.index), axis = 1)
```

but `x.index` is referring to the dataframe index, not the row one, so I'm actually stuck. Moreover, I'm not sure if it's possible to concatenate `int` and `str` values.

EDIT: To be more clear, I need something that works even if I have a longer multi-index (3+ columns) and with `int` type inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["hash"] = (
    df.index.get_level_values(level=0)
    + "/"
    + df.index.get_level_values(level=1)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
              Name     hash
Film  Rating               
Alien 9       Jane  Alien/9
      7       Mark  Alien/7
LOTR  8       Jack   LOTR/8
      6       John   LOTR/6
```

---

Or:

```py
df["hash"] = df.index.map("/".join)
print(df)
```

Comment: First answer works, but I need something more automated in case of longer indexes (3+). Second answer works only if you have string-type indexes, otherwise it gives `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found`. I wanted to know if it's possible to avoid changing the index type. Tried with `'/'.join(map(str, df.index))` but it takes all the index.

Comment: @Schottky Do you mean `df["hash"] = df.index.map(lambda x: "/".join(map(str, x)))` ?